# What is the advantage of using s:url in link tag

Tags: struts2

I have seen at couple of places people using the  inside the  tag to include the css, like below

```
<link href="<s:url value="path_to_css_file" />" rel="stylesheet" />
```

What are we gaining from this. We could have easily written the same code without the  and things would have worked then also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the application context (similar to the JSTL tag), but has S2-specific attributes like `action`, can include/not include current request parameters, etc. ([tag docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/url.html))

If you're not using any S2-specific functionality when you're using it, I'd use the JSTL equivalent.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really know what will be the difference. All I do know it has something to do with 'struts' and apache.

Hope the source might help you put.

Source: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11/docs/url.html